# How to compute the square root of negative numbers?

Tags: ruby, complex-numbers, sqrt

I'm trying to create a complex number from the square root of a negative number using the following code:

```
 include Math
 z = Complex(sqrt(-9))
```

But it produces this error:

```
Math::DomainError: Numerical argument is out of domain - "sqrt"
    from kata2.rb:20:in `sqrt'
    from kata2.rb:20:in `polinomio'
    from kata2.rb:34
    from /home/howarto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
```

How can I build a complex number from the square root of a negative number?

Comment: If you are using libraries, indicate what you are using. What is `c`? Is it a method? Is it a local variable? Is it a numeral? Is it positive? Is it negative? Don't use it without explanation. Don't let us try to guess.

Comment: Sorry, the next time I will put all code. c was a number

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Math.sqrt` function can't compute the square root of negative numbers:

```
irb> Math.sqrt(-1)
Math::DomainError: Numerical argument is out of domain - "sqrt"
...
```

You have to use the [`CMath`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/cmath/rdoc/index.html) module that return complex numbers as needed:

```
irb> require 'cmath'
irb> CMath.sqrt(-1)
# => (0+1.0i) 
irb> CMath.sqrt(-1).class
# => Complex
irb> CMath.sqrt(1).class
# => Float
```